# error with hector quadrotor tutorial

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, ros-tutorials, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!
I've followed the ROS tutorial: "Quadrotor indoor SLAM demo", step by step, (I think) and at the end, when I write the last command,(roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch), I get this:

[indoor_slam_gazebo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [hector_quadrotor_demo] nor is [hector_quadrotor_demo] a launch file name

Somebody knows why?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125456/error-with-hector-quadrotor-tutorial/) by [Irene.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/7306/irene.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you must set the ROS_PACKAGE__PATH enviroment variable.

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:(yours path)

---

Originally posted by [Ste](https://answers.ros.org/users/13491/ste/) with karma: 18 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0